# variable assignment syntax error in python

Tags: python

I have a file,'main.py', with code as:

```
import CreatingTable
CreatingTable.Creating()
```

I get the following error:

In the following code of CreatingData.py there are text files with data in them as follows:

- ConnectionData.txt has localhost,root,FundManagement
- password.txt has password
- CreateTable.txt has Sheet1,SNo,Description

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "main.py", line 1, in <module>

      import CreatingTable                               


    File"/home/tamal/Desktop/Python/FundManagement/FundManagement/CreatingTable.py", line 27

        l = len(s)
        ^    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  ```

The file: 'CreatingTable.py':

```
import MySQLdb

def Creating():
    file02 = open("ConnectionData.txt", "r+")
    strFile = file02.readline()
    s = strFile.split(',')
    file02.close()
    file03 = open("password.txt", "r+")
    pasword = file03.readline()
    file03.close()
    host = s.pop(0)
    user = s.pop(0)
    database = s.pop(0)
    host = str(host)
    user = str(user)
    database = str(database)
    password = str(password)
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host, user, password, database) 
    cur = conn.cursor() 
    file04 = open("CreateTable.txt", "r+")
    strFile1 = file04.readline()
    file04.close()
    s = strFile1.split(',')
    table = s[0]         
    column = s[1]
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (%s)" % (table, column))
    l = len(s)   
    for i in range(2, l):
        column = s[i]
        cur.execute("ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s" % (table, column))
```

Comment: Are you sure you saved this code before running it that time?  I can believe that error would come if you were missing a closing paren on the `execute` line above it, but otherwise this looks pretty good to me, at least on first inspection

Comment: Most of the time, an error like this would indicate that you didn't close your parentheses properly on the previous line. That isn't the case in the code you've shown; in fact, the code you've shown compiles without errors. I would guess that for whatever reason, this isn't the actual code you ran, possibly because you didn't save or because you're looking at the wrong file.

Comment: This code appears to have no errors.

Comment: No I have double checked. In fact I copied the the lines from this website and pasted them still the same error is shown.

Comment: Add an empty line at the top of your file. If the line of the exception stays 27, you are working in the wrong file.

Comment: There might have been some problem but it is working now. Thank You Everyone.